# unicode chars give "unterminated string literal" in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, unicode

This error is generated when my HTML has some weird characters seen as a whitespace.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Some     Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that there is a character between `Some` and `Text`, but it is not seen here. I need to pass this to a function toJson(), but it returns an error saying `unterminated string literal`.

Everything just works fine when I use a simple text instead of this like:

`Some<space>Text` works fine.

I've tried all the str_replace function which I found while searching for the same -

```
1) var re = /(?![\x00-\x7F]|[\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3})./g;
   params.body_html = html.replace(re, '');
   angular.toJson(params); // gives error


2) params.body_html.replace(/\uFFFD/g, '');
   angular.toJson(params); // gives error
```

I don't know what character is this(may be unicode). When I copy this to a emacs file, it is seen as `�`.

Note: You see this character as a red dot when you edit this question and click on `edit the snippet` for the above html.

Any hints/ideas of how I can make this work ?

Comment: It's [that character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm).

Comment: It's working fine for me, see [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bnmxmjp/).

Comment: +1 for js fiddle, Thanks!. But I'm sure it fails due to this only as when I use a normal text "Some Text" instead of this, it works fine. Any idea how it can be fixed ?

Comment: Please provide a non-working JS Fiddle.

Comment: it not working for me because I'm taking all the html as a string into `body_html` and this line separator does some syntax issues with the string. Not sure though.

Comment: U+2028 is allowed in string literals in JSON, but not in JavaScript. Are you trying to execute JSON data as JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working with:

```
params.body_html = params.body_html.replace(/\u2028/g, '');
angular.toJson(params); //works fine.
```

Thanks to @Gothdo for providing the character link.

But the problem is it'll only replace if html has only this particular unicode char. Is there any function with which all unicode characters gets replaced or trimmed ?